# Uninitialized constant Domino::Application::Ckeditor while upgrading Rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Hi I'am need to fix old app on ruby i new in it who can help me with migration form ruby 1.9.3 rails 4.0.1

I need to setup an old website but I can't configure without error

```
$ rails server
Traceback (most recent call last):
    25: from bin/rails:3:in `<main>'
    24: from bin/rails:3:in `load'
    23: from /Users/FightForDObro/Desktop/Done/bin/spring:15:in `<top (required)>'
    22: from /Users/FightForDObro/Desktop/Done/bin/spring:15:in `require'
    21: from /Users/FightForDObro/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/binstub.rb:31:in `<top (required)>'
    20: from /Users/FightForDObro/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/binstub.rb:31:in `load'
    19: from /Users/FightForDObro/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/bin/spring:49:in `<top (required)>'
    18: from /Users/FightForDObro/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/client.rb:30:in `run'
    17: from /Users/FightForDObro/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/client/command.rb:7:in `call'
    16: from /Users/FightForDObro/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in `call'
    15: from /Users/FightForDObro/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in `load'
    14: from /Users/FightForDObro/Desktop/Done/bin/rails:9:in `<top (required)>'
    13: from /Users/FightForDObro/Desktop/Done/bin/rails:9:in `require'
    12: from /Users/FightForDObro/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/railties-5.2.2/lib/rails/commands.rb:18:in `<top (required)>'
    11: from /Users/FightForDObro/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/railties-5.2.2/lib/rails/command.rb:46:in `invoke'
    10: from /Users/FightForDObro/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/railties-5.2.2/lib/rails/command/base.rb:65:in `perform'
     9: from /Users/FightForDObro/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/thor-0.20.3/lib/thor.rb:387:in `dispatch'
     8: from /Users/FightForDObro/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/thor-0.20.3/lib/thor/invocation.rb:126:in `invoke_command'
     7: from /Users/FightForDObro/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/thor-0.20.3/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
     6: from /Users/FightForDObro/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/railties-5.2.2/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:142:in `perform'
     5: from /Users/FightForDObro/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/railties-5.2.2/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:142:in `tap'
     4: from /Users/FightForDObro/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/railties-5.2.2/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:145:in `block in perform'
     3: from /Users/FightForDObro/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.0/gems/railties-5.2.2/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:145:in `require'
     2: from /Users/FightForDObro/Desktop/Done/config/application.rb:10:in `<top (required)>'
     1: from /Users/FightForDObro/Desktop/Done/config/application.rb:11:in `<module:Domino>'
/Users/FightForDObro/Desktop/Done/config/application.rb:35:in `<class:Application>': uninitialized constant Domino::Application::Ckeditor (NameError)
$
```

I try try to fix I expect I fix all error's

Comment: Have you installed the project dependencies using `bundle install` From the stack error it seems you are running it on Ruby 2.6 and Rails 5.2, does it run when you use the original versions? You might want to upgrade to the latest Rails 4.x Before attempting an upgrade to 5.x.

Comment: Thanks you for help. 
Now im Stuck at mysql2 strange error

Comment: An error occurred while installing mysql2 (0.3.20), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install mysql2 -v '0.3.20' --source 'http://rubygems.org/'` succeeds before bundling.

Comment: What happens when you type that? You might want to post a new question, because this seems to be a different issue.